# Select statement that show the name, Job, manager name and salary for all the employees who work in any department with more than 2 employees?

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPk9s.jpg)Hello everyone
I need help in this question please
Select statement that show the name, Job, manager name and
salary for all the employees who work in
any department with more than 2 employees ??
The table is related to Scott and tiger in database (emp table ,dept table ?

My query:

```
select  m.ename manger
      , m.job
      , e. ename employee
from emp m join emp e on (m. empno-e.mer)
where m. deptno in
    (select d.deptno
     from dept d
     where m. deptno=d.deptno
     group by d. deptno
     having count (*) > 2)
```

Comment: What query statements have you tried so far?

Comment: select m.ename manger
,m. job, e. ename employee
from emp m join emp e on (m. empno-e.mer)
where m. deptno
(select d.deptno
from dept d
where m. deptno=d.deptno
group by d. deptno
having count (*)>2)

Comment: OK, format and add that to the question, and include what data were returned, and you'll get more/better responses.

Comment: I put picture include data

Comment: That looks like the raw data.  I mean the result that your query returns.  Also, they don't like pictures in SO because you can't copy/paste stuff to test.

Comment: The result is empty ‍ there is no result

Comment: The table is already in database

Comment: what do you get with the inner query?  `select d.deptno from dept d where m. deptno=d.deptno  group by d. deptno  having count (*)>2`

Comment: `on (m. empno-e.mer)`? Typo?

Comment: It give what I want if I replace “from dept” to “from emp”

Comment: So it's solved?  Well done!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, using longer aliases makes it more readable.

> ```
> select
>   employee.ename as employee_name
> , employee.job   as employee_job
> , employee.sal   as employee_salary
> , manager.ename  as manager_name
> from emp employee
> left join emp manager 
>   on manager.empno = employee.mgr
> where employee.deptno in (
>     select deptno
>     from emp
>     group by deptno
>     having count(*) > 2
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> EMPLOYEE_NAME | EMPLOYEE_JOB | EMPLOYEE_SALARY | MANAGER_NAME
> :------------ | :----------- | --------------: | :-----------
> SCOTT         | ANALYST      |            3000 | JONES       
> FORD          | ANALYST      |            3000 | JONES       
> ALLEN         | SALESMAN     |            1600 | BLAKE       
> WARD          | SALESMAN     |            1250 | BLAKE       
> MARTIN        | SALESMAN     |            1250 | BLAKE       
> TURNER        | SALESMAN     |            1500 | BLAKE       
> JAMES         | CLERK        |             950 | BLAKE       
> MILLER        | CLERK        |            1300 | CLARK       
> ADAMS         | CLERK        |            1100 | SCOTT       
> JONES         | MANAGER      |            2975 | KING        
> BLAKE         | MANAGER      |            2850 | KING        
> CLARK         | MANAGER      |            2450 | KING        
> SMITH         | CLERK        |             800 | FORD        
> KING          | PRESIDENT    |            5000 | null
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=860f3f3760796edd35d65a81243d87b6)*